# Raspberry shutsdown after boot

Tags: boot, noobs

I just got my first RPi, and installed NOOBS on an SD card etc etc. Followed the official guide and all went fine and Raspbian was installed then it shutdown.

So I removed the power plug, waited a while and inserted it again. Now when it boots for a brief second I see the splash screen, then it goes to a white background with the RPi logo and "hold shift for recovery mode" then shuts down very fast. Sometimes I can hold shift and go to the install screen, sometimes it shuts down too fast.

Edit: I'm using a brand new 5V = 1A charger, and tried 3 more before buying the new one. So the power shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the MD5sum of the image file you used to image to the Pi's SD matches the official one? Sometimes a network hiccups and the download glitches. Sometimes this doesn't affect anything, and sometimes it does. Try this first, it often is a cause.

Comment: No I don't know how to do that, and I trusted the official link.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows 7 on my laptop.

Comment: Try looking [here](http://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/) and using this program. It comes in a .zip, so it's portable. From the page: "This page describes md5, a command line utility usable on either Unix or MS-DOS/Windows, which generates and verifies message digests (digital signatures) using the MD5 algorithm....and detection of file corruption."

Comment: OR, if you want to be official, look at Microsoft's FCIV utility [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) From the site: "The File Checksum Integrity Verifier (FCIV) utility can generate MD5 or SHA-1 hash values for files to compare the values against a known good value. FCIV can compare hash values to make sure that the files have not been changed."

Comment: I downloaded fciv but can't get it to run yet. I'm clueless when it comes to CMD. Is it common that the download link gets changed? I used torrent.

Comment: Ok, fciv is working now. But how do I check the md5 of the zip file? When I do -add file | c:\...\noobs_v1_3.zip it opens the file and tells me how to do md5, but not of the zip file. When I do the directory I get an error that its not a file.

Comment: *At least TRY a larger power supply before you start mucking about with anything else.*  The supply you mention is at the low end of the range amperage wise.  If there isn't another one handy right now, then set this aside until there is -- someone, somewhere, must have a 1A+ supply you can borrow for 10 minutes.

Comment: I tried my iPad usb connector (5V=1.0A) with the samsung original usb cable but since apple are such assholes they seem to notice it's not an apple cable and doesn't power it. Is the boot more resource heavy than the installation process? Because there were no issues then.

Comment: @goldilocks Changed to another apple usb connector (5.1V = 2.1A) with the samsung usb cable (might not be able to keep up) and the problem is the same, BUT it doesn't shut down as fast as before. The recovery screen is there for 1-2 more seconds. Might just be a coincidence.

Comment: Ok, try looking [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/software-tools/ht/verify-file-integrity.htm). It provides instructions on how to test the file. Also, Don't test the .zip the ISO comes in, test the .img file.

Comment: Oh, duh. My bad, sorry. NOOBS doesn't use an ISO, that's why it is so good for beginners, it doesn't require any imaging. I am so sorry I messed you up. Yes, you should MD5 the .zip file following the instructions on the FCIV site. Another thing, what version of NOOBS are you using and what SD card? If you are using the newest (NOOBS 1.3) there is a known issue with a certain brand of SD cards.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Haha no problem, yeah that's the one I have, and the sha1 hash was fine, so we can rule that out too. I'm using a SanDisk Ultra 16GB 30MB/s class 10. Is it on the list of bugged cards?

Comment: Crap, just my luck: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=56872&p=435580 What should I install instead?

Comment: Hate it when people get affected by that and similar issues. You can look into getting NOOBS 1.2. It does a similar thing, but no networking and no dual-booting. Or look into Berry-Boot. Or, if you want you can directly write a .img file to the SD card using Win32DiskImager. Best of Luck!

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Ok cool, also they said 1.3 Lite works (it has a fix standard doesnt), so I'll atleast give it a try. Change your comment to an answer so we can close this question. :) Thx for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hustlerinc found his answer thanks to my mentioning of the issue with certain SD cards with NOOBS 1.3 
**Quote:** RPi Awesomeness

> Another thing, what version of NOOBS are you using and what SD card? If you are using the newest (NOOBS 1.3) there is a known issue with a certain brand of SD cards.

He asked me to post as answer, so here it is.

Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to my problem (Question 10210, Sorry I do not know how to make that a link.).
Since you say that you loaded Raspbian perhaps my solution will work for you too.
I gave up on NOOBS and just installed Raspbain directly, following the instructions
here http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads (look under Raw Images).

I know it says it is for advanced users but it is pretty straightforward.

Good luck